«Последние остатки» — речевое излишество или нет?
Задумалась над тем, можно ли говорить «последние остатки». Слово «остатки» и так подразумевает что-то последнее, поэтому и появились сомнения. Буду благодарна за ответ

Последние остатки – здесь нет плеоназма, что видно по словарю:
ОСТАТОК, -тка; м. 1. Оставшаяся неиспользованной, неизрасходованной часть чего-л. Использовать, продать весь о. Значительный о. Небольшой о. О. материи. О. суммы. Остатки запасов. О. пирога. * Остатки сладки (Погов.).
ПОСЛЕДНИЙ, -яя, -ее. 2. Подходящий к концу, иссякающий. Терять п-ее терпение. Собрать п-ие силы. Стараться, бежать из последних сил. П-ие деньги (все, что остались).
Предложения со словосочетанием «последние остатки»
Эта мысль лишила его последних остатков разума, и он почувствовал себя таким беспомощным!
Фрижель, Пленники подземного мира, 2017
Холодом от этих камней больше не веяло, словно они растеряли последние остатки своей магии.
Екатерина Соболь, Медная чайка, 2020
